# How to find out which virtual host is consuming the most resources from the apache 2 server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

I have an Apache Server with about 50 virtual hosts, each virtual host is one of my customers.

How can I see which of these is consuming more resources, like CPU usage, memory, bandwidth, access...

I need to determine who is consuming more resources.